# How to solve quartic equation modulo a composite?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, algebra, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have an univariate polynomial equation over a composite moduli.

Namely the composite is of for $q=(2p)^{2}-1$ where $p$ is odd and $2p-1$ and $2p+1$ are distinct primes.

The modular equation is
$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\equiv0\bmod q.$$

How to find all the roots in mathematica?

Comment: A concrete example in copy-pastable form would help.

Comment: Also check documentation for Roots.